# Learning a transition function of a Markov decision process using infrequently sampled data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, markov-process

I have a dataset of battery trials, where a battery has been charged and discharged in different regimes, and its capacity was measured periodically to reflect the effect of the charging and discharging. This can be easily modeled with a Markov decision process, where the set of actions is the charging/discharging regime options, and the state set is the capacities of the battery.

What I would like to do is to calculate the transition function from the dataset - that is, to understand how different charging regimes affect the state of the battery. If the state (i.e. the capacity), was measured after each charging/discharging, that would be an easy statistical problem - however, the state is measured every 1000 actions.

Does anyone have an idea how can I approach this? The only thing I managed to think about is trying to turn sequences of actions into "bigger actions" (using the action statistics in each action sequence, for example), but this solution isn't good for me as I'm trying to understand the effect of each charging regime separately.